# How to solve Memory management issue in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have 5000 Object from an array.When i execute the loop then my app crashed due to memory Issue.

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 NSMutableString *stringToWrite = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Name,Last Name,Full Name,Phone Number, Email, Birthday,Job, organizationName,Note\n\n"]];
 for(int i = 0 ;i<[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray count];i++)     {
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"firstName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"lastName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"userName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"emailAddress"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"birthday"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"jobTitle"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"organizationName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
      [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"note"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
 }
 NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
 NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *strBackupFileLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentDirectory,@"ContactList.csv"];
 [stringToWrite writeToFile:strBackupFileLocation atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: Can you show us a format how your appDelegate.sortedFilterArray will look like?

Comment: (
{
    birthday = "";
    emailAddress = "abc@gmail.com";
    firstName = Communication;
    imageData = "";
    jobTitle = "";
    lastName = A;
    note = "";
    organizationName = "";
    phoneIdentifier = "CDD2CE63-B50B-4E5B-B41A-D896C5BA8955";
    phoneNumber = "123445677";
    userName = "Communication A";
}
)

Comment: This is one object from an array, like that i have 5000 Objects

Comment: Looking into your array, should the code in your for loop be the other way round?
i.e [[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"firstName"] instead of [[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"firstName"] objectAtIndex:i]

Comment: And try objectForKey instead of valueForKey

Comment: Use core data or at least a plist!

Comment: Thanks Arun its working Now

Comment: 1.You must add autorelase pool atleast.
2.[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray you must get it in temp array just before for loop. Then use temp array in for loop. Ex: [[aTempArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"firstName"]   Or use for in.. loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your for loop like this

```
for(int i = 0 ;i<[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray count];i++)
{
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"firstName"]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"lastName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"userName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"emailAddress"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"birthday"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"jobTitle"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"organizationName"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [stringToWrite appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[[appDelegate.sortedFilterArray valueForKey:@"note"] objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
```